# How to assign template to a component?

Tags: component, templates

Does anyone know how to assign a template to a specific component?
I know I can create menu items and then assign URLs to a template.
But how can I assign a template (not the default) to a component without menu items?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this isn't possible out of the box. I can imagine such a functionality can easily be added by a custom plugin which checks the current component and then set the required template.

Comment: Did some digging. Looks like Peter from RegularLabs has your back. https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/advanced-template-manager/

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying to avoid another extension

Comment: @NunoNogueira: In my answer on the following link (although it proved that the OP had asked a different question),  - I describe how a such plugin would look like: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/21997/assign-different-single-article-template-per-category/21998#21998. As for trying to avoid another extension - note that especially the plugin system is designed for this exact purpose. To give you the ability to hook into the Joomla operation and adjust how it behaves, especially for cases like this. So a plugin here is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:
https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/advancedtemplatemanager
but not work with all Joomla template framewoek such as Gantry